# Select em duas tabelas com dados da primeira tabela?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Em uma tabela que contem alguns comentários, uma das colunas guarda o ID do usuário que fez esse comentário, como posso recuperar os dados desse usuário com o ID no momento de fazer uma consulta na tabela de comentários? sei que posso fazer dois select um após o outro, mas se possível gostaria de recuperar todos os dados em um select só.

Tabela de comentários:

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
| id_usuario     | serie       | data | comentario    |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
| varchar(255)   | varchar(255)| date | varchar(255)  |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
```

Tabela de usuários:

```
+----------------+-------------+------+------+
| id_usuario     | apelido     | email       |
+----------------+-------------+------+------+
| varchar(255)   | varchar(255)| varchar(255)|
+----------------+-------------+------+------+
```

Como ficaria o select?

Comment: Seria interessante adicionar a estrutura das tabelas, para facilitar a resposta.

Comment: Atualizei com uma parte das duas tabelas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isso você só precisa fazer um `JOIN` que irá vincular uma tabela a outra de acordo com o `id_usuario`:

```
SELECT usr.*,
       com.*
  FROM comentarios com
       INNER JOIN usuarios usr ON usr.id_usuario = com.id_usuario
```

Caso você tenha uma restrição por `WHERE` ficará assim:

```
SELECT usr.*,
       com.*
  FROM comentarios com
       INNER JOIN usuarios usr ON usr.id_usuario = com.id_usuario
 WHERE usr.id_usuario = 1
```

Comment: Se houver uma clausula WHERE para a tabela de comentários devo inserir após o "FROM comentarios"?

Comment: Não, o `WHERE` sempre fica no final. Vou colocar um exemplo

Comment: @LeoLetto adicionei no exemplo

Comment: Poderia mudar também para recuperar somente o apelido do usuário que fez o comentário, como essas são informações que vão ficar visíveis no código fonte, não gostaria de deixar outros dados do usuário que comentou tão fáceis

Comment: Sim, você só precisa identificar os campos que quer retornar na primeira parte do `SELECT`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM usuarios u
JOIN comentarios c ON c.id_usuario = u.id_usuario
```

No seu caso é ideal fazer o select ordenado no data de comentario recentes paras os antigos, e verificar se realmente tem um comentário tem algum conteudo

Da seguinte forma

```
SELECT * 
FROM usuarios u
JOIN comentarios c ON c.id_usuario = u.id_usuario
WHERE c.comentario <> null
ORDER BY c.data desc
```

Comment: No caso não seria necessario verificar se tem comentário null, pois só é salvo no BD de houver o comentário não estiver vazio agradeço a preocupação, vou testar seu método tb